# How to target the NavLink component with css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to get NavLink to apply CSS styles in react. But I can not target NavLink.

**Code:**

```css
.navUl li NavLink {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav className='myNavbar'>
                <ul className='navUl'>
                  <li>
                    <NavLink activeClassName='active' exact to="/">Function</NavLink>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <NavLink activeClassName='active' exact to="/class">Class</NavLink>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <NavLink activeClassName='active' exact to="/users">Logout</NavLink>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

How do I target the NavLink component with css?

Comment: NavLink is not a valid element in HTML. If you're using a custom SGML or XML language, css support browsers might be limited.

Comment: have you tried `.navUl li .active` ?

Comment: HTML uses `class` for classes. Your code has `className`. That won't work. Are you using some kind of Framework around HTML? If so, you need to address the HTML DOM that gets generated by the framework, not the raw source.

Comment: First of all I don't quite understand your question! what you exactly wants to do?? Provide your entire `React Code` not just `HTML` part.

Comment: `NavLink` is this your component or part of a library? I don't fully understand why you are trying to style it in this particular component

Answer (score 1):

`NavLink` change to `a` in html

So your class should be like this

```
.navUl li a{
  ...
}
```

Comment: It is not an appropriate solution for this problem!

Comment: I know, it works. There is no NavLink element in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using `styled-components` then**

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

/* The First Method */
export const NavLink = styled.a`
  // your style goes here
`;

/* The Other Method */

const NavLink = styled.a`
  // your style goes here
`;

export default NavLink;
```

---

**And if you are using `functional-components` then**

```js
export default function NavLink(...props) {
  return <a href="" {...props}> </a>
}
```

`...props` will let you any property you want like

`<a href="" style="" className="" ...andMuchMore> </a>`

---

**And if just `jsx` then it will look something like this**

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="/home" className="nav-link"> Home </a>
  <a href="/about" className="nav-link"> About </a>
</nav>
```

I don't use `class components` so often so I don't quite know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `NavLink` passes props to underlying JSX, you should be able to pass a `className` prop to the NavLink components which will be rendered as the `class` attribute in the html that react renders.

Then you can target it with a regular css class selector.

```
// styles.css

.navUl li .navLink {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

```
// App.js

import "./styles.css";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <nav className="myNavbar">
      <ul className="navUl">
        <li>
          <NavLink className="navLink" activeClassName="active" exact to="/">
            Function
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            className="navLink"
            activeClassName="active"
            exact
            to="/class"
          >
            Class
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            className="navLink"
            activeClassName="active"
            exact
            to="/users"
          >
            Logout
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit silly-clarke-jv9mo]